# Count bookings per trip - return 0 if none

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,

```
CREATE TABLE `voyages` (
`voyage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`voyage_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
`voyage_groupBooking` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`voyage_live` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`voyage_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`voyage_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`voyage_slug` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`voyage_shortDescription` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_shortPageDescription` text NOT NULL,
`voyage_tag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_detail` text NOT NULL,
`voyage_ageBracket` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '14-18',
`voyage_included` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_image` text DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_startDate` date NOT NULL,
`voyage_startTime` time NOT NULL,
`voyage_endDate` date NOT NULL,
`voyage_cost` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
`voyage_miles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_hours` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_ports` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_deposit` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`voyage_crewBerth` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`voyage_Afterguard` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`voyage_map` text DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_mapZoom` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 8,
`voyage_addressName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_streetAddress` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_locality` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_postalCode` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_region` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_country` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`voyage_gallery` text DEFAULT NULL,
`voyage_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
`booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`booking_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`booking_reference` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_stripeCustomerReference` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_stripeDepositInvoice` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_stripeBalanceInvoice` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_depositCharged` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`booking_balanceCharged` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`booking_totalPaid` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`booking_voyageID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`booking_firstName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_lastName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_dob` date NOT NULL,
`booking_gender` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`booking_nationality` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_passport` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_mobile` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_house` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_street` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_city` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_county` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_postcode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`booking_medical` text NOT NULL,
`booking_allergies` text NOT NULL,
`booking_swim` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_diet` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergFirstName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergLastName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergHouse` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergStreet` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergCity` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergCounty` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_emergPostCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergMobile` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_emergPhone` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_emergRelationship` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_dec1` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_dec2` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_dec3` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_dec4` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`booking_media1` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
`booking_media2` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
`booking_contractEmail` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`booking_contractName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`booking_contractDate` date NOT NULL,
`booking_adminNotes` text DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to count how many bookings there are based on each voyage and if none return a 0.

e.g:

```
Voyage 1 = 0, 
Voyage 2 = 3, 
Voyage 3 = 5
```

and so on.

At them moment I have the following, but it doesn't seem to be working. I only have one row of test data in the bookings table at the moment and 17 voyages in the voyage table.

```
SELECT voyage_name, voyage_id, bookings.booking_voyageID, 
COUNT(bookings.booking_voyageID) AS bookingcount
FROM voyages
LEFT JOIN bookings ON voyages.voyage_id = bookings.booking_voyageID
ORDER BY voyage_name asc
```

I need my SQL query to return a count of 0 if there are no bookings.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is excess - remove it. ON clause condition is enough.

Comment: This returns a count of the voyages by voyage name sadly, I need it to count how many bookings per voyage ideally. Thanks for help!

Comment: Provide: complete tables CREATE TABLE scripts; INSERT INTO scripts with some sample data; desired output for this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think count will suffice your problem, since if there is a row for voyage, it will return 1 and will not return 0.

`SUM` is what you want with custom column.

Try this

```
SELECT 
  voyage_id, 
  bookings.booking_voyageID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.booking_voyageID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 
bookingcount
FROM 
  voyages
LEFT JOIN 
  bookings 
ON 
  voyages.voyage_id = bookings.booking_voyageID
GROUP BY
  voyage_id
ORDER BY
  voyage_id;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a21db/27)